por que tengo este erro: undefined reference to `Isoceles::Isoceles(float, float)'| ||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
El código la función que realiza es calcular el área y perímetro de varia figura ya calcula el de triangulo y el de una figura genera pero falta isósceles y otra figuras el error dice que no es: referencia indefinida a `Isósceles::Isósceles(flotante, flotante) y también me dice otro error que parece se enlaza con el primer error: error: ld devolvió 1 estado de salida espero que me pueda ayudar lo agradecería mucho  a qui les proporciono el código el error esta en maint.cpp, les comparto todo el código con los archivos de encabezado y cpp.
#ifndef PROGRAMA_H_INCLUDED
#define PROGRAMA_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include "figura.h"
#include "triangulo.h"
#include "isoceles.h"
using namespace std;

class Programa {
private:
Figura *m_f;
public:
Programa() : m_f() {} // Constructor para inicializar m_f
~Programa()
{ delete m_f; } // Destructor para liberar la memoria asignada
void PedirDatos() {
    int opc, val, val1, val2;
    cout << "Menu\n";
    cout << "1-. Figura\n";
    cout << "2-. Triangulo\n";
    cout << "3-. Isoceles\n"; // Añadido opción para Isoceles
    cout << "Que figura quieres calcular?\n";
    cin >> opc;

    switch (opc) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Elegiste figura\n";
            cout << "Proporciona los lados de la figura\n";
            cin >> val;
            m_f = new Figura(val);
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "Elegiste triangulo\n";
            cout << "Proporciona los lados del triangulo\n";
            cin >> val >> val1 >> val2;
            m_f = new Triangulo(val, val1, val2);

            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Elegiste isoceles\n";
            cout << "Proporciona los lados del isoceles\n";
            cin >> val >> val1;
            m_f = new Isoceles(val,val1);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Opción no válida\n";
            break;
    }
}

void MostrarResultado() {

        if(m_f->GetNumLados() == 3){
       cout << "El area y perimetro es:\n";
        cout << "Numero de lados"<<m_f->GetNumLados()<< endl;
        cout << "Area: " <<((Triangulo*) m_f)->Area() << endl;
        cout << "Perimetro: " <<((Triangulo*) m_f)->Perimetro() << endl;
        }
        else if(m_f->Area()==0){
        cout << "El area y perimetro es:\n";
        cout << "Numero de lados"<<m_f->GetNumLados()<< endl;
        cout << "Area: " <<m_f->Area() << endl;
        cout << "Perimetro: " <<m_f->Perimetro() << endl;
        }
}

void Run() {
    PedirDatos();
    MostrarResultado();
}
};

#endif // PROGRAMA_H_INCLUDED

a qui esta el archivo triangulo.cpp
 #include "triangulo.h"

// Constructor
Triangulo::Triangulo(float p_Lado1, float p_Lado2, float 
 p_Lado3)
:Figura(3){
m_Lado1=p_Lado1;
m_Lado2=p_Lado2;
m_Lado3=p_Lado3;
}
Triangulo::Triangulo( Triangulo & otro ):Figura(otro)
{
m_Lado1= otro.m_Lado1;
m_Lado2= otro.m_Lado2;
m_Lado3= otro.m_Lado3;
}
// Función para calcular el área
 float Triangulo::Area()
{
 return m_Lado1 * m_Lado2 / 2;
}

// Función para calcular el perímetro
float Triangulo::Perimetro()
{
return m_Lado1 + m_Lado2 + m_Lado3;
}

el archivo de encabezado de triangulo.h
#ifndef TRIANGULO_H
#define TRIANGULO_H

#include "figura.h"

class Triangulo : public Figura {
private:
float m_Lado1; //!< Member variable "m_Lado1"
float m_Lado2; //!< Member variable "m_Lado2"
float m_Lado3; //!< Member variable "m_Lado3"
public:
/** Default constructor */
Triangulo(float p_Lado1=0, float p_Lado2=0, float p_Lado3=0);

 Triangulo( Triangulo & otro);
/** Default destructor */
virtual ~Triangulo() {}

void SetLado1(int val){
m_Lado1=val;
}
int GetLado1(void){
return m_Lado1;
}
void SetLado2(int val1){
m_Lado2=val1;
}
int GetLado2(void){
return m_Lado2;
}
void SetLado3(int val2){
m_Lado3=val2;
}
int GetLado3(void){
return m_Lado3;
}
public:
float Area();
float Perimetro();
};
#endif // TRIANGULO_H

el archivo figura.cpp
#include "figura.h"

 Figura::Figura()
{
m_NumLados=0;  //ctor
}
Figura::Figura(int val)
{
m_NumLados=val;
}
Figura::Figura(Figura& otro)
{
m_NumLados = otro. m_NumLados;
}
Figura::~Figura()
{
//dtor
}
float Figura::Area(){return 0;}
float Figura::Perimetro(){return 0;}

el archivo figura .h
#ifndef FIGURA_H
#define FIGURA_H


class Figura
{
private:
int m_NumLados;
public:
//constructores
    explicit Figura();

    explicit Figura(int);
     Figura(Figura&);
//Destructores
    virtual ~Figura();
//Setter y Getter
void SetNumLados(int val)
{
m_NumLados=val;
}
int GetNumLados(void)
{
return m_NumLados;
}
//Propiedades
    float Area();
    float Perimetro();
};

#endif // FIGURA_H

el archivo isoceles.cpp
#include "isoceles.h"
Isoceles::Isoceles(float p_iguales, float p_desiguales): Triangulo( 
p_iguales, p_desiguales, p_iguales)
{

}
Isoceles::Isoceles( Isoceles & otro ): Triangulo(otro)
{

}

y por ultimo el archico isoceles.h
#ifndef ISOCELES_H_INCLUDED
#define ISOCELES_H_INCLUDED
#include "triangulo.h"
class Isoceles : public Triangulo {
private:
float m_iguales; //!< Member variable "m_Lado1"
float m_desiguales; //!< Member variable "m_Lado2"
public:
/** Default constructor */
 explicit Isoceles(float p_iguales=0, float p_desiguales=0);

 Isoceles( const Isoceles & otro);
/** Default destructor */
virtual ~Isoceles() {}

void Setiguales(int val){
m_iguales=val;
}
int Getiguales(void){
return m_iguales;
}
void Setdesiguales(int val1){
m_desiguales=val1;
}
int Getdesiguales(void){
return m_desiguales;
 }

public:
float Area();
float Perimetro();
};


#endif // ISOCELES_H_INCLUDED


Muestra el código de isosceles.cpp

listo ya subí todo el código y todos los archivos

Si ese es todo tu código tienes un problema en el archivo isoceles.h: usas la clase Triangulo sin haber incluído antes #include "triangulo.h" por lo tanto el compilador no sabe qué significa Triangulo.

En el archivo isoceles.cpp tienes que incluir el nombre de la clase al acual pertenecen los métodos que defines. Debes escribir los nombres de los dos constructores de esta manera: Isoceles::Isoceles

Cuando en le primer constructor de Isoceles llamas al constructor de la clase madre te sobra la palabra float: las llamadas a funciones deben incluir los argumentos: no sus tipos.

En los constructores de Isoceles estás tratando de acceder a m_Lado1. Esto es un atributo privado de la clase Triangulo por lo tanto no puedes acceder a él desde fuera de la clase. Si quieres que Isoceles pueda acceder a los atributos de la clase base debes marcarlo como protected.

Cuando implementas las funciones por fuera de la clase, debes poner el nombre de la clase seguido de 2 puntos antes del nombre de la función. Isoceles::Isoceles(...)

ya lo modifique como comentan pero el error todavía continua dejen actualizo el código
